# plumbum: How to send a variable to stdin?

Tags: python, plumbum

I currently do:

```
(local['echo'][var] | sth)()
```

Which seems inelegant and inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in the [plumbum documentation](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/local_commands.html#input-output-redirection):

You can use the shift-left operator `<<`.

```py
from plumbum import local

if __name__ == '__main__':
    var = "some text in a python variable"

    sth = local["cat"]

    x = (local['echo'][var] | sth)()
    print(x)

    print("alternative:")
    x = (sth << var)()
    print(x)
```